# ReferenceError: $ is not defined in Angular JS

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Hi i am getting 'ReferenceError: $ is not defined' in my code.
This is my sample code

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
        // redirect to login page if not logged in and trying to access a restricted page
        var restrictedPage = $.inArray($state.current.name, ['login']) === -1;
        var loggedIn = $rootScope.globals.currentUser;
        if (restrictedPage && !loggedIn) {
            $state.go('login');
        }
    });
```

This code am writing inside run();

Comment: That means jquery not defined,check whether u called the jquery library properly!!

Comment: Did you include a script for jQuery?

Comment: When i pass the jquery reference through CDN its working, but when did same by bundle.js using require('jquery/dist/jquery.js'); its not working. @Lokesh_Ram

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add jquery file in your project. `$` means jQuery.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a NodeJS project, you can install [jquery](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery), then import the jquery library. e.g.

**Console: (run from project root)**

`npm install jquery`

**Javascript: (insert in header of your `.js` file)**

`var $ = require('jquery');`